# Filename vs. FileStream - what should I use as argument for file writing?

Tags: c#, file, filestream, file-writing

I am creating a class to handle file-writing to a custom file format our company uses.

Since the data-acquisition workflow that generates the file content is comprised of multiple steps (and as such of multiple "bursts" of data-recording alternated with variable-duration pauses so that the user can reconfigure the sensors during the same recording session), I wonder how to handle opening and closing of `FileStream` along the whole procedure.

I am in doubt about the following options:

====

```
// 1) WriterClass receives path as argument and handles FileStream internally
var writer = new WriterClass(filepath);
var datasource = new datasource();
writer.configure(configInfo);
writer.start();
writer.record();
// some time passes while data is received and saved
writer.pause();
writer.resumeRecording();
writer.stop();
writer.finish();
```

====

```
// 2) Client code handles FileStream itself, and passes it to WriterClass as argument

using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filepath)
{
    var writer = new WriterClass(stream);
    var datasource = new datasource();
    writer.configure(configInfo);
    writer.start();
    writer.record();
    // some time passes while data is received and saved
    writer.pause();
    writer.resumeRecording();
    writer.stop();
    writer.finish();        
}
```

====

Currently option 2 seems a lot easier to me, since the filestream is guaranteed to remain open during the whole Writer lifecycle (which makes sense to the application intent, by the way), but is there anything that I should take into account? Is there a problem in keeping a FileStream open for a potentially indefinite amount of time (due to `pause` and `resumeRecording` arbitrary nature)?

On the other hand, option 1 leaves to the WriterClass itself to handle stream opening and closing, but I tried to implement it and it raised a lot of seemingly unnecessary complication, since I had to handle opening and closing of the stream in almost every method. Worst yet would be to represent a stateful stream as a property of WriterClass (I didn't even try).

Finally, it would be healthy to consider what would happen (file corruption vs file recoverability) with a partially written file if the application crashes before the acquisition procedure is complete.

Comment: Any reason you're writing a custom writer and not using something like a `StreamWriter` or `FileWriter`?

Comment: The `using` keyword saves you all the close and flush and memory and w/e business with files. All in all, I'd prefer to have both options available in the library.

Comment: **IMO** Both. In a simple scenario 1) is easier (but it **must** also implement IDisposable). For a complex scenario 2) is more flexible (what about a comrpessed stream? An archive? A network stream?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw my WriterClass uses BinaryWriter internally, so that I can encapsulate the actual writing with meaningful method names.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I thought about that too: having a Stream is much more frexible that having a file-path (from which I could only derive a _File_ Stream).

Comment: The critical issue: is all data written to disk if something crashes while in pause mode? If you use `Flush()` in `writer.pause()` this should be fine. Then it should be ok to leave the stream open for a long time.

Comment: @DrKoch not only, probably he has a consumer(s)/producer scenario and he _may_ want to share a thread-safe stream (for example) instead of sharing file access with _retry pattern_ and/or locked file parts. He may even need to have an in-memory only version (with async flush? depends on how critical is to always save data within seconds). That's scenario where I would have a stream instead of a file path.

Comment: FileStream fsAppend = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", FileMode.Append);    
StreamWriter swAppend = new StreamWriter(fsAppend);